# Add a foreign key to AbstractUser

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have this two models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass



class Listing(models.Model):
    listing_id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listing")
```

I would like to do the following in the User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But i'm getting the following error:
`NameError: name 'Listing' is not defined`

Is it possible to add a foreign key to abstractuser?

Comment: You can't refer to `Listing` before it is defined. And it looks like your `User` class is written before your `Listing` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you define `User` *before* `Listing`, the name is not yet defined. This is however not a problem for Django since you can use a *string literal* as well:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    listing = models.ForeignKey('Listing', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Listing(models.Model):
    listing_id = models.AutoField(
        auto_created=True,
        primary_key=True,
        serialize=False,
        verbose_name='ID'
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='listing'
    )
```

You can however not define a `ForeignKey` with the name `listing` here, since you already have an `ForeignKey` in your `Listing` model with as `related_name='listing'`. This would thus result in an error. You thus should either change the `related_name`, or rename the `listing` in the `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the model name as a string to avoid issues where you want to reference a model that is not yet defined

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    listing = models.ForeignKey('Listing', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can also use the same method to refer to a model in another app by adding the app name

```
listing = models.ForeignKey('app.Listing', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```